# OpenCV array is totally different from raster values of my TIFF in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, python, raster, numpy, opencv

I have a a GeoTIFF that I need to binarize. OpenCV is of course the choice program for the job, but I am having major issues.

Below, you will see a typical range for RGBnIR values in QGIS of my image:

[image: values of a single pixel]

First, the GeoTIFF is in UInt16, which I know is not supported by OpenCV. However, I can't seem to convert it/scale properly in QGIS to an 8bit unsigned integer. When I do, and open it up in OpenCV, there is simply no data in the numpy array >0.

Confusingly, when I send the UInt16 data to OpenCV, I get these values, which make no sense (they should be up to a maximum of just over 1000 but the maximum is just 10):

[image: histogram and sample of array values]

I just want to create a simple binary image, but can't do that unless the number scales line up here...